# Can't access $location in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access $location in my controller and I am not having any luck. Below is my controller code.

```
bwApp.controller('bidding-controller', [
  '$window', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebase', '$location', 
  '$compile', '$interval','$bwAppState', 'bidwrangler_api', 'AuctionService', 
  'CompanyService', 'NavigationService', 'UserService',
  function($window, $scope, $rootScope, $firebase, $location, $compile, $interval,
           $bwAppState, bidwrangler_api, AuctionService, CompanyService, 
           NavigationService, UserService) {

     $scope.toggle_auction = function(item) {
       if ($bwAppState.user.type == "clerk" && !item.listing) {
         $window.location.href = "/clerk/" + item.auction.id + "?item=" + item.id;
       }
       else {
         var restore_pos = null;
         if ($location.search().section == 'itmes') {
           restore_pos = $('.all-items').scrollTop();
           $('.all-items').one('scroll', function(){$('.all-items').scrollTo(restore_pos)});
         }
         else if ($location.search().section == 'user_items'){
           restore_pos = $('#your-items').scrollTop();
           $('#your-items').one('scroll', function(){$('#your-items').scrollTo(restore_pos)});
         }

         NavigationService.update_push_state({item: item.id, section: 'auction'});
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

When I am checking `$location.search().section` I keep getting an error in the console. If I am outside of `$scope.toggleAuction()` I have access to it. I have included/injected it correctly into the controller so I don't understand why I can't access it inside of the $scope function.

The error that I receive looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: How are you calling `toggle_auction `

Comment: @Zack are you injecting the `$location` in the services `NavigationService' properly also check the code under `$bwAppState` is erroring out instead of inside the controller, not sure what `$bwAppState` does

Comment: on an ng-click. I ended up just putting the method in a service instead of a controller though and it works as expected now.

Comment: Can you do something like `var location = $location` and use `location` in your function? Not saying that's good practice but worth checking. Can you prepare jsfiddle with similar issue?

Comment: $location.search is an object not function